# Postgresql : syntax error at or near "(" when adding a column

Tags: postgresql, calculated-columns, postgresql-10

I've been trying to add stored generated column with this command

```
ALTER TABLE mtn_order
ADD COLUMN textsearchable_index_col tsvector
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english', coalesce(descr, '') || ' ' || coalesce(descrrep, ''))) STORED;
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 3: GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english', coalesce(descr, ...
                            ^
```

What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
Had to upgrade to version 12

Comment: What does `select version();` show you?

Comment: PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-2.pgdg18.04+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit
(1 row)

Comment: Generated columns were introduced in Postgres 12. You will have to upgrade if you need them.

Comment: i'll try, thank you

Comment: i this you should use `ALIAS` instead of `AS`